# Is anything wrong with Selenium, while testing proxy with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, selenium, capybara

When lunching tests with Capybara, Selenium, Firefox (windows) I am using this type of code

```
  Capybara.reset_sessions!
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new

  profile["network.proxy.type"] = 1 # manual proxy config
                                    #profile["network.proxy.http"] = "209.188.18.130"
  profile["network.proxy.ssl"]  = "**********"
  profile["network.proxy.ssl_port"]             =   ****

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :profile => profile)
  end
```

But it seems to me that even with configuration the browser is not secured. For example using the same proxy in real Browser not in testing environment I get no problems making a signup to a new site . But when I do a test with Selenium Firefox Capybara even if I change many proxies - The site sees through it.

The question is: Is there any possibility to configure Selenium Firefox Capybara so that it should be protected as a real browser?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The best way is to manually configure a browser and read its prefs.js file to see what the configuration actually is, then put that information in your profile going in to the constructor.  This is what I set up:

```
   profile["network.proxy.no_proxies_on"] = NO_PROXY_SETTING
   profile["network.proxy.backup.ftp"] = ""
   profile["network.proxy.backup.ftp_port"] = 0 
   profile["network.proxy.backup.socks"] = ""
   profile["network.proxy.backup.socks_port"] = 0 
   profile["network.proxy.backup.ssl"] = ""
   profile["network.proxy.backup.ssl_port"] = 0 
   profile["network.proxy.ftp_port"] = PROXY_PORT
   profile["network.proxy.ftp"] = PROXY_HOST
   profile["network.proxy.http_port"] = PROXY_PORT
   profile["network.proxy.http"] = PROXY_HOST
   profile["network.proxy.share_proxy_settings"] = true
   profile["network.proxy.socks_port"] = PROXY_PORT
   profile["network.proxy.socks"] = PROXY_HOST
   profile["network.proxy.ssl_port"] = PROXY_PORT
   profile["network.proxy.ssl"] = PROXY_HOST
   profile["network.proxy.type"] = 1 # manual proxy config
```